# Connect google cloud platforum instance with VNCSERVER

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, tcp, google-cloud-storage, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect my VM's instance hosted on google cloud platform with vncserver.

I have vnc server installed and everything on my instance vm. I tried to create a secure ssh tunnel like this : gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-a tunnel -- -N -p 22 -D localhost:5000

Then I'am trying to connect with my vm with vnc server : vnc server ip : externalipadress:5901

But it doesn't work.

I also tried this command : gcloud compute ssh --zone   -- -N -p 5901 -D localhost:5901

but it says : (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you configured your firewall properly?   
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: I think the problem was related to the port number. I opened all my port and it was working. Thank you